# Using Live Connect API in ASP.NET to retrieve a user's contacts

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get a full information for an user's contacts. I'm using Live sdk with the scope:

> wl.basic%20wl.contacts_emails%20wl.contacts_phone_numbers

But I only get the following JSON.

```
     "id": "contact.15e8e034000000000000000000000000", 
     "first_name": "ngo", 
     "last_name": "dat", 
     "name": "ngo dat", 
     "is_friend": false, 
     "is_favorite": false, 
     "user_id": null, 
     "email_hashes": [
        "28b54848ca9abc28bcad50cce0a0bc496fd36c3a8b87827d5f19d684c97b03d9", 
        "f0751fc86d4fd4b946363cd691f6c2269e641337de7b27df92e368b0c18ddb8e", 
        "60e52789536e7fdc543ba6781b5b804b54a0537ecb9375db706a724668734c77"
     ], 
     "updated_time": "2016-04-19T04:49:31+0000", 
     "emails": {
        "preferred": "npdat_personal@tma.com.vn", 
        "account": null, 
        "personal": "npdat_personal@gmail.com", 
        "business": "npdat_work@gmail.com", 
        "other": "npdat_other@gmail.com"
     }, 
     "phones": {
        "personal": null, 
        "business": null, 
        "mobile": null
     }
```

I want to access middle name and fax property but can't find it anywhere in the return JSON.

Please tell me what method of GET call do I need to retrieve full information?

Comment: Middle name and fax data is not coming in ur JSONresult data, so please check the source first

Comment: @Spark Sorry can't understand the term 'source'? Did you mean the link or the contact information on Live?

Comment: source means the thing which is giving you this output JSON, liek ur database or some other api

Comment: @Spark I use Live API from Microsoft to retreive information from Live account which contain account contact's information. This API require scope to access information.
In this link I can't see any scope that give me an access to middle name and fax: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243646.aspx

Comment: yes, you are not getting the middle name and fax property from this source

Comment: @Spark So do you know any way to walkaround this or I must accept that I can't get 2 properties that I want?

Comment: why are you using that source, if possible make your own source(api)

Comment: @Spark Because it will be more time-consuming then use already provided API by Microsoft.

Comment: Its not that time consuming,  it will 10-20 min if you are using static data for test purpose.

Comment: @Spark Thanks, I will research more. I'm a new guy with this so it will take more them than usual. :)